# jquery popup added overflow-y: hidden; after open/close

Tags: jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I have a popup page to login/register user.

but I have a problem. when I open popup, jquery added `overflow-y: hidden;` to `html` tag, after close popup it will be keep on `html` tag.

I think I have two solution that I don't know how to do them:

1. I remove this style after closed popup.
2. I change jquery functions .

Answer (score 0):

After your Jquery plugin you could do as you recommended first, remove the style.

You can achieve this with `$('html').css('overflow-y', 'auto');` ~ CBroe

Apply that when you Jquery login plugin closes. Type that command into the console and you will see that it works.

Comment: _“You can achieve this with `$('html').removeAttr('style');`”_ – that is not a proper way of doing this. `$('html').css('overflow-y', 'auto')` would be better suited.

Comment: I see that also works, please explain why that is better.

Comment: F.e. because the element might have other styles set (maybe from other scripts/plugins), that you don’t want to remove as well. Plus, removing the style attribute has (had) some compatibility issues, IIRC.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense, thanks. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem was `magnific.js` popup library :

```
$('html').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
```